# antd modal on modal click not opening

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I have an **antd modal** as shown in the below code, Now when I select `Create Manual` and click `Next`, `I want to close this modal and open another Modal2` but another modal is not getting opened after clicking next.

Here is my code. ( Codesandbox live demo - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4103-forked-ixffq?file=/index.js) )

Please suggest a workaround to get his second modal generated. Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Modal, Button, Radio } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectRadio, setselectRadio] = useState("preselect");
  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };
  const select = (e) => {
    // you can save the value in here
    setselectRadio(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  function modalclick() {
    if (selectRadio === "preselect") {
      alert("pre-select");
    } else {
      //---------------> UNABLE TO OPEN ANOTHER MODAL HERE   <-------------------------------------
      <Modal title="Create Test Suite" visible={isModalVisible}>
        MODAL 2 COMES HERE
      </Modal>;
      alert("manual");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={showModal}>
        Create Test Suite
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Create Test Suite"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        footer={[
          <Button key="cancel" onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}>
            Cancel
          </Button>,

          <Button type="primary" key="next" onClick={modalclick}>
            Next
          </Button>
        ]}
      >
        <Radio.Group
          defaultValue="preselect"
          buttonStyle="solid"
          onChange={(e) => {
            select(e);
          }}
        >
          <Radio value="preselect">Create from Preselect</Radio>
          <Radio value="manual">Create Manual</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the modal 2 you can use a ***useState** hook* or a ***useRef** hook*. In both methods, **you need first to put this modal 2 in the return** of your "App".

**useState way**: Just use a *state* to control the visibility, like how you do in *modal 1*, simple.

**useRef way**: This is a little more complex. You will need to use a **useImperativeHandle** inside the modal component, and create a function (inside too) to control the visibiliity. So, in your page, you can just call the function that is inside the component, to show the modal. Using this method, the logic about the state control of visibility leaves the page and goes into the component.

Comment: Thanks... `useState` way worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Modal2 is not visible because is out of the return of App function. Put Modal 2 inside return and try again.